# Review star images are missing

Tags: product, review

I added a new review to my newly added product and approved it from the backend. It is showing 1 review and link, but does not showing the review image yellow star. So please help me to bring this star in the product detail page

Thanks
[image: review links on product page]

Comment: could you try to disable the theme and see if the default theme also has the same issue.

Comment: Is it trying to load the image and failing? Try using your browser's developer tools and see if it's 404'ing the file, or not requesting at all, etc.

Comment: Hi..It is showing Image could not load. It is showing as an background image. request to help me out from this issue

Comment: @David Manners I disabled the theme and it is working in default theme perfectly

Comment: Hi..Friends..I solved this and thank you for all your support..Actually the image was missing....